# how to delete all values in Core Data Values and then how to store values in Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, core-data

In my application, i'm using `Core Data` to store values. First am storing 30 row of values for month and retrieving that values one by one every day but am not deleting the row daily. after this 30 days complete. On 31st day i need to clear all those data stored in  `Core Data` and have to check the webservice and have to retrieve the data from service and store the values getting from service.Have to do this for every month.

Is it Possible?

Comment: Your question is much too broad and too vague. Everything you have mentioned is possible. What is your specific programming problem? - Perhaps have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq, http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/, or http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx for information about good questions.